# How should "My Status as an Assassin Obviously Exceeds the Hero's" be tagged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There is a question asking about this series: [What kind of demon is in "My Status as an Assassin Obviously Exceeds the Hero's"?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/61402/what-kind-of-demon-is-in-my-status-as-an-assassin-obviously-exceeds-the-heros)

Researching for possible titles from the internet:

- My Status as an Assassin Obviously Exceeds the Hero's (53 characters)
- Ansatsusha de Aru Ore no Status ga Yuusha yori mo Akiraka ni Tsuyoi no data (75 characters)

However, there is a limitation that a tag can only be up to 35 characters long, and I didn't find any short nickname for this, official or not.

How should this series be tagged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

For this specific case, the series has been tagged as [my-status-as-an-assassin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-status-as-an-assassin) with a synonym of [ansatsusha-de-aru-no-ore-ga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ansatsusha-de-aru-no-ore-ga).

Answer (score 8):

Since we are an English language site. We should set up a precedence from now on about tagging.

I propose the following:

1. If the title has official English localized name, use that. Meaning take the official English name over the Japanese name were available. Both should be synonyms.

- If it does not, use the Japanese romanized name until such a time that there is. Then synonymize the English name onto it (i.e. replacing it as the main tag). Update the tag excerpt and wiki to reflect as needed.

2. If the full title exceeds the character limit, then either: Use the official or widely fan accepted abbreviated Japanese or English abbreviated name (if applicable), e.g. Oreimo.

- If there is no (official or otherwise) abbreviated name, use up to the first 5 words plus or minus two so the title doesn't feel cut off. In the case of the afforementioned series, it can be either. [ansatsu-de-aru](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ansatsu-de-aru) or [my-status-as-an-assassin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-status-as-an-assassin). The ideal acceptance criteria would be that it is distinguishable by it as a partial title.
- Both would be synonyms of one another, with the English name taking precedence (i.e. is the main tag) where applicable.
- If there ever is an official abbreviated name or widely accepted (search results will be used as a benchmark) name within fan circles we can go with that.
- The tag wiki should be updated to reflect abbreviations as needed.

3. For very edge cases of very generic names, we can handle them on a case by case basic here on meta.

This should cover around 75% of cases involving series-related tagging.