# Can we add [love-chunibyo-and-other-delusions] as a synonym of [chuunibyou-demo-koi-ga-shitai]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [chuunibyou-demo-koi-ga-shitai](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chuunibyou-demo-koi-ga-shitai) currently has the synonym [love-chunibyo-delusions](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/love-chunibyo-delusions), most probably due to the old 25 character limit on tag names. Since the limit has been upped to 35 characters, the full English title of the series now fits within the limit. So, could we have [love-chunibyo-and-other-delusions](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/love-chunibyo-and-other-delusions) as a synonym? If yes, we could also remove the old synonym, I expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The main tag has been changed to [love-chunibyo-and-other-delusions](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/love-chunibyo-and-other-delusions) with [chuunibyou-demo-koi-ga-shitai](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chuunibyou-demo-koi-ga-shitai) as a synonym.** 'love-chunibyo-delusions' has been removed from the synonym.

This is according to the [2021 Policy Review: How do we want to name series tags?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4414/2516).

> 1. If the title has official English localized name, use that. Meaning take the official English name over the Japanese name were available. Both should be synonyms.

Comment: Would you prefer similar requests to be made in new Meta posts, or just informally in chat? If the former, is it more convenient for you if I compile multiple requests into a single post, or would you prefer separate posts for each request (or is either fine)?

Comment: @Namaskaram personally, I prefer to have separate posts on the meta for each request so that each can be discussed independently. Chat is hard for documentation.

Comment: Noted! I spotted maybe a couple of tags that might need similar synonymization. I'll write up the requests into individual Meta posts, when I get time tomorrow.