# Can we reverse the direction of the synonym between the tags [hataraku-maou-sama] and [the-devil-is-a-part-timer]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

From the [2021 Policy Review: How do we want to name series tags?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4414):

> 1. If the title has official English localized name, use that. Meaning take the official English name over the Japanese name were available. Both should be synonyms.

We currently have the tag [hataraku-maou-sama](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hataraku-maou-sama), which has the synonym [the-devil-is-a-part-timer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-devil-is-a-part-timer). Can we reverse the direction of the synonym, so that the latter tag is the parent? This would be in line with the current policy quoted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done.** [the-devil-is-a-part-timer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-devil-is-a-part-timer) is now the main tag, with [hataraku-maou-sama](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hataraku-maou-sama) as its synonym.