# Can we create the tag [cells-at-work] and make the tag [hataraku-saibou] its synonym?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

From the [2021 Policy Review: How do we want to name series tags?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4414):

> 1. If the title has official English localized name, use that. Meaning take the official English name over the Japanese name were available. Both should be synonyms.

If I'm not mistaken, the series "Hataraku Saibou" has an official English title: "Cells at Work!" So, can we create the tag [cells-at-work](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cells-at-work) and make [hataraku-saibou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hataraku-saibou) its synonym? I think this would be in line with the above quoted policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Done.** [cells-at-work](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cells-at-work) is now the main tag, with [hataraku-saibou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hataraku-saibou) as its synonym.