# Can we create the tag [kaguya-sama-love-is-war] and make the tag [kaguya-sama-wa-kokurasetai] its synonym?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

If I'm not mistaken, the series "Kaguya-sama wa Kokurasetai: Tensai-tachi no Ren'ai Zunōsen" has an official English title: "Kaguya-sama: Love Is War". So, can we create the tag [kaguya-sama-love-is-war](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kaguya-sama-love-is-war) and make [kaguya-sama-wa-kokurasetai](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kaguya-sama-wa-kokurasetai) its synonym? I think this would be in line with the [current policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4414).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done.** [kaguya-sama-love-is-war](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kaguya-sama-love-is-war) is now the main tag, with [kaguya-sama-wa-kokurasetai](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kaguya-sama-wa-kokurasetai) as its synonym.