# Can we reverse the direction of the synonym between the tags [kimi-no-na-wa] and [your-name]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently, the tag [kimi-no-na-wa](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kimi-no-na-wa) is the parent tag, and it has the synonym [your-name](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/your-name). Can we reverse the direction of the synonym to make the parent tag as the one with the English title? I think this would be in line with the [current policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4414).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done.** [your-name](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/your-name) is now the main tag, with [kimi-no-na-wa](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kimi-no-na-wa) as its synonym.