# Can we add synonyms to the tag [rascal-does-not-dream-of-bunny-girl]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [rascal-does-not-dream-of-bunny-girl](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rascal-does-not-dream-of-bunny-girl) for the series "Rascal Does Not Dream of Bunny Girl Senpai" currently has no synonym. I suggest that we add the following synonyms (refer to the [current policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/2021-policy-review-how-do-we-want-to-name-series-tags) on tagging and synonymization):

- The Japanese title "Seishun Buta Yarō wa Bunny Girl Senpai no Yume o Minai" is quite long, and does not fit within our 35 character limit on tag names. So, I suggest that we create the synonym [seishun-buta-yarou-wa-bunny-girl](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seishun-buta-yarou-wa-bunny-girl).
- It might be good to also have the partial name [bunny-girl-senpai](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bunny-girl-senpai) as a synonym. The [current policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/2021-policy-review-how-do-we-want-to-name-series-tags) does not suggest adding pieces of a long title other than the initial part as synonyms; but, I think an exception can be made in this case, as "bunny girl senpai" is (I believe) a more common shortening of the English title than "rascal does not dream".
- On similar lines, we might consider having [seishun-buta-yarou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seishun-buta-yarou) as a synonym instead of the longer [seishun-buta-yarou-wa-bunny-girl](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seishun-buta-yarou-wa-bunny-girl), since (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rascal_Does_Not_Dream_of_Bunny_Girl_Senpai)) it seems that "Seishun Buta Yarō" is the title by which the light novel series is commonly known in Japan.
- The series is also popularly abbreviated as "AoButa" (as mentioned on [MAL](https://myanimelist.net/anime/37450/Seishun_Buta_Yarou_wa_Bunny_Girl_Senpai_no_Yume_wo_Minai), for instance), so I suggest adding [aobuta](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aobuta) as a synonym.

Lastly, I think the tag [aobuta](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aobuta) ought to be the primary tag, with the rest as synonyms, based on what the [tagging policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/2021-policy-review-how-do-we-want-to-name-series-tags) says regarding series names that are too long to fit within the character limit but which also have a widely accepted abbreviation (namely, use the abbreviation as the primary tag).