# Can we add synonyms to the tag [reincarnated-as-a-slime]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [reincarnated-as-a-slime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reincarnated-as-a-slime) for the series "That Time I Got Reincarnated as a Slime" currently has no synonyms. I suggest we add the following synonyms (refer to the [current policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4414) on tagging and synonymization):

- The current tag name has 23 characters, possibly due to the former limit of 25 characters for tag names. Since we can now use up to 35 characters in a tag name, we could have [that-time-i-reincarnated-as-a-slime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/that-time-i-reincarnated-as-a-slime) as a synonym.

  In fact, if this suggestion is acceptable, it might even be good for the longer name to replace the current one (rather than one being a synonym of the other) since the shorter name is a substring of the longer one.
- Alternatively (or additionally), we could have the tag [that-time-i-got-reincarnated-slime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/that-time-i-got-reincarnated-slime) as a synonym, by taking all the words that are capitalized in the series name. Of course, there is some ambiguity in this, but I am using [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_Time_I_Got_Reincarnated_as_a_Slime) as a reference here.
- The Japanese title of the series is "Tensei Shitara Slime Datta Ken", so we could have the tag [tensei-shitara-slime-datta-ken](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tensei-shitara-slime-datta-ken) as a synonym.
- The series is also abbreviated as "TenSura", so we could have the tag [tensura](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tensura) as a synonym.
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_Time_I_Got_Reincarnated_as_a_Slime) says that the series is also known as "Slime Isekai". So, we could add the tag [slime-isekai](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slime-isekai) as a synonym.

Lastly, I think the tag [tensura](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tensura) ought to be the primary tag, with the rest as synonyms, based on what the [tagging policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4414) says regarding series names that are too long to fit within the character limit but which also have a widely accepted abbreviation (namely, use the abbreviation as the primary tag).