# Can we add the synonym [kanojo-okarishimasu] to the tag [rent-a-girlfriend]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [rent-a-girlfriend](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rent-a-girlfriend) for the series "Rent-A-Girlfriend" currently has no synonym. So, can we add a synonym using the Japanese title "Kanojo, Okarishimasu", namely [kanojo-okarishimasu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kanojo-okarishimasu)? I think this would be in line with the [current policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4414) on tagging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done.** [kanojo-okarishimasu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kanojo-okarishimasu) is now a synonym of [rent-a-girlfriend](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rent-a-girlfriend).

Answer (score 0):

There's no use cases of [kanojo-okarishimasu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kanojo-okarishimasu), so why would we synthetically create it?  I don't see that there's a need right now.

Comment: As per my reading of the linked policy, the Japanese title should be a synonym of the English title. Am I mistaken?

Comment: You're probably not but I don't see a reasonable way to synonymize a tag that doesn't exist.

Comment: I was under the impression moderators have some magic powers to take care of this. ;) If it would help, I can create the tag [kanojo-okarishimasu] and shoot off a couple of questions under it. :)

Comment: I wouldn't want you to artificially create the tag if the Correct™ one exists already.

Comment: All right-y. :)