# Can we add the synonym [muno-na-nana] to the tag [talentless-nana]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [talentless-nana](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talentless-nana) for the series *[Talentless Nana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talentless_Nana)* currently has no synonym. So, can we add a synonym using the Japanese title *Munō na Nana*, namely [muno-na-nana](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muno-na-nana)? I think this would be in line with the [current policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/2021-policy-review-how-do-we-want-to-name-series-tags) on tagging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done.** [munou-no-nana](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/munou-no-nana) is now a synonym of [talentless-nana](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talentless-nana).

*Note: I used the transliteration of [*munou*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/41619/Munou_na_Nana) because that's how it's spelled in Japanese.