# Can we reverse the direction of the synonym between the tags [mahouka-koukou-no-rettousei] and [the-irregular-at-magic-high-school]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently, the tag [mahouka-koukou-no-rettousei](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mahouka-koukou-no-rettousei) is the parent tag, and it has the synonym [the-irregular-at-magic-high-school](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-irregular-at-magic-high-school). Can we reverse the direction of the synonym to make the parent tag as the one with the English title? I think this would be in line with the [current policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4414).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done.** [the-irregular-at-magic-high-school](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-irregular-at-magic-high-school) is now the main tag, with [mahouka-koukou-no-rettousei](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mahouka-koukou-no-rettousei) as its synonym.