# Can we reverse the direction of the synonym between the tags [kyoukai-no-kanata] and [beyond-the-boundary]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently, the tag [kyoukai-no-kanata](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kyoukai-no-kanata) is the parent tag, and it has the synonym [beyond-the-boundary](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beyond-the-boundary). Can we reverse the direction of the synonym to make the parent tag as the one with the English title? I think this would be in line with the [current policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4414).

Comment: BTW, please feel free to let me know if I'm posting these requests too rapidly. My impression is that since there's no hurry to handle these requests, it's better to just make a post once I come across a possible improvement in synonymization instead of waiting and then forgetting about it. But if it's bothersome to see a bunch of these on the front page of Meta then I can slow down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done.** [beyond-the-boundary](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beyond-the-boundary) is now the main tag, with [kyoukai-no-kanata](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kyoukai-no-kanata) as its synonym.