# Can we create the tag [so-im-a-spider-so-what] and make the tag [kumo-desu-ga-nani-ka] its synonym?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

If I'm not mistaken, the series "[Kumo Desu ga, Nani ka?](https://myanimelist.net/anime/37984/Kumo_Desu_ga_Nani_ka)" has the official English title, "So I'm a Spider, So What?" Can we create the tag [so-im-a-spider-so-what](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/so-im-a-spider-so-what) and make [kumo-desu-ga-nani-ka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kumo-desu-ga-nani-ka) its synonym? I think this would be in line with the [current policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/2021-policy-review-how-do-we-want-to-name-series-tags) on tagging.

Comment: Separately, I'm not sure whether it should be "nani-ka" or "nanika" in the tag for the Japanese title (or whether it doesn't really matter). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_I%27m_a_Spider,_So_What%3F) gives the Hepburn transliteration of the title as "Nanika", but MAL (linked in the post) gives "Nani ka".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done.** [so-im-a-spider-so-what](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/so-im-a-spider-so-what) is now the main tag, with [kumo-desu-ga-nani-ka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kumo-desu-ga-nani-ka) as its synonym.

As for "*nani ka*" or "*nanika*", "*ka*" is a Japanese particle (just like "*ga*") and usually stands alone. However, "[*nanika*](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BD%95%E3%81%8B)" is also a single expression, meaning "(so) what (are you trying to say)?". Since there are far more results for "*nani ka*" (with space), I decided to use the current tag as-is. (Not that I think it will affect so much though...)