# Can we reverse the direction of the synonym between the tags [uchouten-kazoku] and [the-eccentric-family]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently, the tag [uchouten-kazoku](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uchouten-kazoku) is the parent tag, and it has the synonym [the-eccentric-family](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-eccentric-family). Can we reverse the direction of the synonym to make the parent tag as the one with the English title? I think this would be in line with the [current policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/2021-policy-review-how-do-we-want-to-name-series-tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done.** [the-eccentric-family](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-eccentric-family) is now the main tag, with [uchouten-kazoku](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uchouten-kazoku) as its synonym.