# Can we reverse the direction of the synonym between the tags [kenka-banchou-otome] and [girl-beats-boys]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently, the tag [kenka-banchou-otome](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kenka-banchou-otome) is the parent tag, and it has the synonym [girl-beats-boys](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/girl-beats-boys). Can we reverse the direction of the synonym to make the parent tag as the one with the English title? I think this would be in line with the [current policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/2021-policy-review-how-do-we-want-to-name-series-tags).

Comment: Hmm, upon further consideration, it is not clear to me that "Girl Beats Boys" is really the English title, and not a subtitle for the anime series. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenka_Bancho_Otome:_Girl_Beats_Boys) offers "Fighting Delinquents Girl Leader", but I can't find this title in use anywhere other than in the Wikipedia article. [MAL](https://myanimelist.net/anime/34501/Kenka_Banchou_Otome__Girl_Beats_Boys) doesn't list it, for instance. Perhaps it would be more accurate to create [tag:kenka-banchou-otome-girl-beats-boys] instead? This fits in the 35 character limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit complicated.

*Kenka Banchou Otome* is actually a [media mix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_mix). In this case, the *Kenka Banchou Otome* series originally started as [a PS Vita game](https://otome-games.fandom.com/wiki/Kenka_Bancho_Otome). Later in 2015, a manga titled *[Kenka Banchou Otome ～Koi no Battle Royal～](https://otome-games.fandom.com/wiki/Kenka_Bancho_Otome_%EF%BD%9EKoi_no_Battle_Royal%EF%BD%9E)* (also known as [*Kenka Bancho Otome: Love's Battle Royale*](https://www.viz.com/kenka-bancho-otome-love-s-battle-royale)) was published. Then in 2017, an anime adaptation titled [*Kenka Bancho Otome -Girl Beats Boys-*](https://www.crunchyroll.com/kenka-bancho-otome-girl-beats-boys-) was broadcast.

**However,** looks like Viz licensed the series as *Kenka Bancho Otome: Girl Beats Boys* instead? As per [an article on AnimeNewsNetwork](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2017-07-01/viz-media-adds-fire-punch-and-kenka-bancho-otome-girl-beats-boys-manga-sisyphean-novel/.118276) and [a tweet by Viz](https://twitter.com/vizmedia/status/881261710048362496) when they licensed *the "Love's Battle Royale" manga*,

> Announcement! @ShojoBeat has acquired Kenka Bancho Otome: Girl Beats Boys!

As such, I'm still not sure if using Viz's naming as the tag makes sense in this case since the subtitle for the manga is actually different.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! It seems it's best to stick with the current tag names and synonymization direction.