# Can we add the synonym [tate-no-yuusha-no-nariagari] to the tag [rising-of-the-shield-hero]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [rising-of-the-shield-hero](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rising-of-the-shield-hero) for the series "The Rising of the Shield Hero" currently has no synonym. So, can we add a synonym using the Japanese title "Tate no Yūsha no Nariagari", namely [tate-no-yuusha-no-nariagari](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tate-no-yuusha-no-nariagari)? I think this would be in line with the [current policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/2021-policy-review-how-do-we-want-to-name-series-tags) on tagging.

Additionally, it might be good to rename the master tag to add the article "the" at the beginning, since the official title seems to include it, and we now have enough space to do so (the current English tag name uses precisely 25 characters, but we can now go up to 35 characters in tag names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done.** [the-rising-of-the-shield-hero](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-rising-of-the-shield-hero) is now the main tag, with [tate-no-yuusha-no-nariagari](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tate-no-yuusha-no-nariagari) as its synonym.