# Can we add synonyms to the tag [bofuri]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [bofuri](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bofuri) for the series "Bofuri: I Don't Want to Get Hurt, so I'll Max Out My Defense" currently has no synonyms. I suggest we add the following synonyms (refer to the [current policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/2021-policy-review-how-do-we-want-to-name-series-tags) on tagging and synonymization):

- Since the English title is too long to fit within 35 characters, we could clip it to [i-dont-want-to-get-hurt-so-ill-max](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/i-dont-want-to-get-hurt-so-ill-max), which takes up 34 characters.
- Since the Japanese title "Itai no wa Iya nano de Bōgyoryoku ni Kyokufuri Shitai to Omoimasu" is also incredibly long, we could clip it to [itai-no-wa-iya-nano-de-bougyoryoku](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/itai-no-wa-iya-nano-de-bougyoryoku), which also comes to 34 characters.
- Lastly, I suggest that we keep the primary tag as [bofuri](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bofuri), since it seems to be the official abbreviation for this series.