# Can we create the tag [haikyu] and make the tag [haikyuu] its synonym?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I know this is probably a trivial request, even to the point of redundancy, but...

The [current policy on tagging and synonymization](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/2021-policy-review-how-do-we-want-to-name-series-tags) says to prefer the English title over the Japanese title for any series tag. The anime and manga series *Haikyū!!* (Japanese: ハイキュー!!) currently has the associated tag [haikyuu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haikyuu), but no synonyms. Unless I'm mistaken, the English title of the series is *Haikyu!!*, without the [macron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron_(diacritic)) over the letter 'u'.

So, could we create the tag [haikyu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haikyu) and make the tag [haikyuu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haikyuu) its synonym?

(Just for the sake of consistency... I understand that if someone searches for `haikyu` in the Tags page, then [haikyuu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haikyuu) will turn up as a suggestion, so it's not a "problem" that needs solving, as such.)