# Can we add synonyms to the tag [genkoku]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [genkoku](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genkoku) for the series "How a Realist Hero Rebuilt the Kingdom" currently has no synonyms. I suggest we add the following synonyms (refer to the [current policy on tagging and synonymization](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/2021-policy-review-how-do-we-want-to-name-series-tags)):

- Since the English title is too long to fit within 35 characters, we could clip it to [how-a-realist-hero-rebuilt-the](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-a-realist-hero-rebuilt-the), which takes up 30 characters.
- Since the Japanese title "Genjitsu Shugi Yūsha no Ōkoku Saikenki" is also too long to fit within the character limit, we could clip it to [genjitsu-shugi-yuusha-no-oukoku](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genjitsu-shugi-yuusha-no-oukoku), which also comes to 31 characters.
- The series is also given the English title "Re:CONSTRUCTION - The Elfrieden Kingdom Tales of Realistic Brave", according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=How_a_Realist_Hero_Rebuilt_the_Kingdom&oldid=1070883066#cite_note-2). So, I suggest we also add as synonyms the tags [re-construction](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/re-construction), as well as any clipped version of the subtitle, such as:

  - [the-elfrieden-kingdom-tales-of](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elfrieden-kingdom-tales-of): 30 characters; OR
  - [the-elfrieden-kingdom-tales-of-real](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elfrieden-kingdom-tales-of-real): 35 characters; OR
  - [elfrieden-kingdom-tales-of-realisti](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elfrieden-kingdom-tales-of-realisti): 35 characters; etc.
- Lastly, I suggest that we keep the primary tag as [genkoku](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genkoku), since it seems to be the abbreviation commonly used for this series.