# Can we add synonyms to the tag [ascendance-of-a-bookworm]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [ascendance-of-a-bookworm](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascendance-of-a-bookworm) for the series "Ascendance of a Bookworm" currently has no synonyms. I suggest we add the following synonyms (refer to the [current policy on tagging and synonymization](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/2021-policy-review-how-do-we-want-to-name-series-tags)):

- The Japanese title is "Honzuki no Gekokujō", so we could add the synonym [honzuki-no-gekokujou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/honzuki-no-gekokujou).
- The *full* Japanese title appears to be "Honzuki no Gekokujō: Shisho ni Naru Tame ni wa Shudan o Erandeiraremasen". Since the subtitle part is incredibly long, perhaps we could add a truncation as a synonym, such as [shisho-ni-naru-tame-ni-wa-shudan-o](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shisho-ni-naru-tame-ni-wa-shudan-o), which takes up 34 characters.
- Perhaps the English version of the subtitle, "I'll Stop at Nothing to Become a Librarian", could also be added as a synonym in a truncated form, such as [ill-stop-at-nothing-to-become-a-lib](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ill-stop-at-nothing-to-become-a-lib) (which uses the full 35 characters) or [ill-stop-at-nothing-to-become-a](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ill-stop-at-nothing-to-become-a) (which uses 31 characters). I'm not entirely sure whether this is an official English translation of the subtitle of the series, though...