# Can we create the tag [mysterious-play] and make the tag [fushigi-yugi] its synonym?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

If I'm not mistaken, the series "Fushigi Yûgi" was officially released in English under the title, "Mysterious Play" (source: [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=178)). So, can we create the tag [mysterious-play](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysterious-play) and make the tag [fushigi-yugi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fushigi-yugi) its synonym? I think this would be in line with the [current policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/2021-policy-review-how-do-we-want-to-name-series-tags) on tagging.

Separately, I'm not sure whether the appropriate romanization of the Japanese title should be "Fushigi Yugi" or "Fushigi Yuugi". I'm aware that a [macron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron_(diacritic)) over the letter "u" is romanized as "uu"—in [wāpuro rōmaji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%C4%81puro_r%C5%8Dmaji), is it?—but I don't know what to do with a [circumflex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex). (As one might have guessed, I am unable to read the actual Japanese title "ふしぎ遊戯".)