# Can we reverse the direction of the synonym between the tags [quan-zhi-gao-shou] and [the-kings-avatar]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently, the tag [quan-zhi-gao-shou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quan-zhi-gao-shou) is the parent tag, and it has the synonym [the-kings-avatar](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-kings-avatar). Can we reverse the direction of the synonym to make the parent tag as the one with the English title? I think this would be in line with the [current policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/2021-policy-review-how-do-we-want-to-name-series-tags).

Separately, I'm not sure whether the tag with the Chinese title ought to be [quan-zhi-gao-shou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quan-zhi-gao-shou) or [quanzhi-gaoshou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quanzhi-gaoshou). At least on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_King%27s_Avatar_(2017_web_series)) and [MAL](https://myanimelist.net/anime/33926/Quanzhi_Gaoshou) the Chinese title "全职高手" is romanized as "Quánzhí Gāoshǒu" or simply "Quanzhi Gaoshou". Is this significantly different from "Quan Zhi Gao Shou"?