# Can we add the synonym [gods-blessing-on-this-wonderful] to the tag [konosuba]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [konosuba](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/konosuba) for the series "KonoSuba: God's Blessing on This Wonderful World!" currently has the synonym [kono-subarashii-sekai-ni-shukufuku](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kono-subarashii-sekai-ni-shukufuku), from the Japanese title "Kono Subarashii Sekai ni Shukufuku wo!". Can we also add a synonym using the English (sub)title, namely [gods-blessing-on-this-wonderful](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods-blessing-on-this-wonderful), which takes up 31 characters?

Cf. the current policy on tagging: [2021 Policy Review: How do we want to name series tags?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4414/60264).