# Can we add synonyms to the tag [mushoku-tensei]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [mushoku-tensei](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mushoku-tensei) for the series "Mushoku Tensei: Jobless Reincarnation" currently has no synonyms. I suggest we add the following synonyms (refer to the [current policy on tagging and synonymization](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/2021-policy-review-how-do-we-want-to-name-series-tags)):

- The tag [jobless-reincarnation](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobless-reincarnation), from the English subtitle, could be added as a synonym.
- The tag [isekai-ittara-honki-dasu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isekai-ittara-honki-dasu), from the Japanese title "Mushoku Tensei: Isekai Ittara Honki Dasu", could also be added as a synonym.
- I'm not sure whether the literal translation of the Japanese subtitle, "I Will Seriously Try If I Go To Another World" is actually used anywhere (although [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mushoku_Tensei) and [MAL](https://myanimelist.net/anime/39535/Mushoku_Tensei__Isekai_Ittara_Honki_Dasu) do list it); if necessary we could also add a truncation of this as a synonym, such as [i-will-seriously-try-if-i-go-to](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/i-will-seriously-try-if-i-go-to), which takes up 31 characters.